# Check string in list but with wildcard character

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I'm feeling RegEx is the way to go but I like the simplicity of my list so far and I'm not too in depth with RegEx just yet..

I need to be able to cycle through this list:

```
dat_list = ["Red_Ball","Yellow_Ball","Purple_Ball","Green_Ball"]

> "Red_Ball" in dat_list
    True

> "Purple_Turnip" in dat_list
    True

> "Beige_Sandwich" in dat_list
    False
```

I know I can also just check against the list but it won't check against it for wildcard strings like "Purple_Turnip"..

Comment: If you're checking for membership within a unique set of values, you should be using a set. It's O(1) time complexity and much faster than using `in` with a list. membership testing for lists is O(n).

Comment: I gotcha, I definitely need to do my research into that. By chance do you have an example?

Comment: `set([iterable]` returns a set. So you can do `dat_set = set(["Red_Ball","Yellow_Ball","Purple_Ball","Green_Ball"])`. The `in` keyword will work the same way as it does for lists, only it will be faster because sets are implemented with a hash table instead of a lengthy array type thing.

Comment: Anyways can you explain more what you mean by "wildcard"?

Comment: Like the string won't be exact. An example would be "Agent 3432598 Signed On" and I have to match it to be `true` with "Agent Signed On"

Answer (score 1):

Just checking for membership in a list (or set) is straightforward, but if you want to filter a list based on a pattern, you can't (trivially) gain the performance benefits of a hashtable lookup, so you might as well go back to list comprehensions.

```
[item for item in alist if re.match(expr, item)]
```

or

```
[item for item in alist if item.startswith(pat)]
```

or even

```
rx = re.compile(expr)
filter(rx.match, alist)
```